# jquery refresh the iframe but it is not permanent

Tags: jquery

```
$('#idOfMyButton').click(function() { 
$('#idOfMyIframe').attr('src', 'the new url'); });
```

this code works and it load new url but again it refresh and back to initial status which I set in design mode it happens in a second.

Comment: script is in the header and in document.ready function

Comment: Do you have any handler attached to the `iframe`'s `load` event?

Comment: Can you try and state the problem again. What is refreshing? Have you any other code running, can you try to reproduce the issue at jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that because you are missing `return false;`. To be honest your question isn't very clear.

```
$('#idOfMyButton').click(function() { 
  $('#idOfMyIframe').attr('src', 'the new url'); 
  return false;
});
```

This will prevent the button from carrying on and refresh the page

Comment: use event.preventDefault() rather than return false!